# В функцию getDatasetConfiguration() не передается параметр

Tags: php, umi

В ядре umi.cms есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
/**
     * Возвращает настройки табличного контрола
     * @param string $param контрольный параметр (чаще всего - название текущей вкладки
     * административной панели)
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDatasetConfiguration($param = '') {
        return [
            'methods' => [
                ...
            ],
            'default' => 'name[400px]'
        ];
    }
```

В системных модулях передается этот параметр и в зависимости от него формируется вывод. Но когда я пишу эту функцию в своем модуле, $param всегда равен null. Проверял вот таким способом:

```
public function getDatasetConfiguration($param = '')
{
    if ($param === null) {
        return [
            'methods' => [
                [
                    'title' => getLabel('smc-load'),
                    'forload' => true,
                    'module' => 'testModuleUnika',
                    '#__name' => 'objects'
                ]
            ],
            'default' => 'name[400px]'
        ];}}
```

Как мне получить / где передать этот параметр?

На сколько я понимаю, вызов происходит другой системной функцией:

```
private function getDataSetConfig($type = null) {
        $type = $type ?: getRequest('param');
        $allowedModuleList = (array) cmsController::getInstance()
            ->getCurrentModule();

        /** @var umiEventPoint|iUmiEventPoint $event */
        $event = Service::EventPointFactory()
            ->create('dataset_config', 'before', $allowedModuleList)
            ->setMode('before')
            ->setParam('type', $type);
        $event->call();

        $datasetConfig = $this->getDatasetConfiguration($event->getParam('type'));

        $event->setMode('after')
            ->setParam('config', $datasetConfig)
            ->call();

        return $event->getParam('config');
    }
```

Без переопределения в своем модуле, данные не выводятся вовсе.

Comment: Вы в своём модуле переопределяете public function getDatasetConfiguration? А где происходит её вызов?

Comment: @Quazimorda дополнил вопрос

Comment: 1. Есть ли ещё места, где бы вызывалась данная функция? 2. Вызовы происходят уже после того, как вы переопределяете её у себя или до этого? 3. Где именно формируется передаваемый параметр? Где ему присваиваются значения?

Comment: @Quazimorda спасибо, нашел ответ. Проблема была именно в присвоении значения параметру и я не знал где в юми это сделать. Если интересен ответ, смотрите ниже, там всё расписал

Comment: В случае, когда справка по модулю, фреймворку или CMS не дала ответа, начинаю искать вхождение нужной мне подстроки в файлах проекта, обычно это помогает разобраться. Рад, что вы всё выяснили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Как раз был вопрос в присвоении значения, место присвоения было не очевидным для меня, а на umi help не нашел такой информации. Пришлось для того, чтобы найти ответ, сломать один из системных модулей.

По итогу нужно при создании верстки для шаблона передать данный параметр подобной строкой:

```
<xsl:with-param name="control-params" select="$method" />
```

Пример полной верстки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet SYSTEM "ulang://common/dummy">

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="result[@method = 'pages']/data">
        <div class="layout">
            <div class="column">
                <xsl:call-template name="ui-smc-table">
                    <xsl:with-param name="control-params" select="$method" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```